# What is faster communicating using a messenger or an intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, parcelable, messenger

If you have activities that communicate with a service, or another service communicating with a service, which "communication protocol" is faster to deliver it's message to the binding party?

Messages that are transmitted to/from the service are all strings or parcelable objects.

I am having difficulties deciding which method is faster if you want to send bulk data to another service or activity. I cannot find details about the processing speed of Intents or Messages sent by a Messenger.

Anybody experience with this?

Comment: Would you have trouble timing both?

Comment: @cHao: what do you mean exactly? I need the fastest way to communicate between activity/service and service/service.

Comment: I mean that it doesn't exactly sound difficult to try out both and observe any performance differences between the two.  And frankly, if it matters *that* much, then you'd be a fool to take anyone else's word re: which is faster; any differences will be highly dependent on your particular use case.

Comment: @cHao: true about the fool thing :) But any advise (if it is or isn't true at all) is welcome. More people = more answers = better clues to judge what is right and what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider LocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcastSync() 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html#sendBroadcastSync(android.content.Intent)

If your activities and services are in the same process then it is is better to use LBM since it is faster and more secure.  And it gives you the option of sending a broadcast 'sync' which means it is handled immediately, so it would probably qualify as 'fastest', even though messages/handler are otherwise faster then intents/receivers.

Comment: Nice tip, thx! Another thing is when I go from service to service (in the same process), I read that a message (Messenger 2 Messenger) is handled within the same UI-Thread (main Thread). If I need to forward a message to another Thread within a service, I need to handle the message coming from the "other" service in the Main-Thread handler which handles it next in the Threads-handler. And vise versa. I assume this is faster than with an Intent (how do you forward an Intent received in the service to another Thread within that service??). Besides that Messages are reused with .obtain() :)

Comment: ... and I don't recall that Intent objects are reusable (assumption!), so that adds to the creation time (speed of communication). Your tip of the LBM is good for use when I want to tell multiple clients something has changed, but I am not sure if it will be faster, I think it is more convenient (assumption!). How would you test which one is faster for equal and fair comparison? Any ideas?

Comment: Please elaborate on the "more secure" part of your answer. You mean more secure compared to normal Intent messaging or more secure compared to Messengers messages?

Comment: Local intents are more secure then regular intents because they stay within the process.  Regarding speed, I'm not sure whether you are measuring CPU time to invoke and receive, or the time between invoke and receive (e.g. latency).  I think LBM sendBroadcastSync is best if your concern is latency; with the other options there is high variability in the latency.

Comment: In your example above of sending a message from one service to another service but then handling it in a secondary thread, I think you might consider an IntentService - the system will deliver the intent to the secondary thread for you.

Comment: An extra IntentService is no go (it has to be within one service, because of hardware communication). I actually would like the least amount of latency and the least cpu time. I am not sure if there is any difference noticable between a LBM sendBroadcastSync and Messengers (if the message has to be sent to multiple clients). My assumption is that messages end up in each Messengers queue (which can be flooded with other msgs for one Messenger, but not for another Messenger). So, if I need to signal something and all clients must react directly, I think I am better off using LBM.

Comment: Yes, if all clients must react directly, then I think LBM is the best choice.

Comment: @user504342 No problem, but if you think my answer is correct, please mark it.

Comment: \@Tom: both answers are correct. That of minhaz and yours, so which one should I pick? I think minhaz has some good points about the IntentResolver, your answer is good as well. What the heck, you have my vote :)

Answer (score 5):

For Intent, [IntentResolver](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/com/android/server/IntentResolver.java) required time to find appropriate target as it will search through list of receivers. This case performence will depend on your system and number of receivers, IntentResolver required to search to find appropriate receiver.

On the other side if you send [Message](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html) through [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), it will use the Message Queue of the same thread and that case performance will depend on available message on that Queue.

So seems like message going to be faster then Intent or at least theoretically, but you can always write a short program to see the output.

But, if you have lots of data from to send from service to Activity you can think of another alternative solution where you write the data to a persistence store and after just notify your Activity that data is ready. upon receiving the notification Activity read the data from data source. In this way, if user receive a phone call or get disrupted in between you data is safe.

Comment: It is also needed to do service/service communication, so in that case there is no need for persistence storage. My guess is to use Messengers to handle the traffic instead of Intents. Also between Threads it's better to use Messages (which can be forwarded to another Messengers Queue). I don't know how to communicate between Threads using Intents. These are assumptions on my part. I was hoping somebody already figured this out...